Converting a python dictionary containing vibration signal data to a Tensorflow dataset
I have been working on a vibrational signal dataset which I have preprocessed into a dictionary which contains 10 keys. Each key in the dictionary corresponds to a class and the value associated with it is a 2 dimensional array in which containing unique sequences vibration data 'n' sample points long.
I have been looking for a way to convert this dictionary into a tensorflow dataset to input to a 1D CNN.
I have tried Integer labelling each row corresponding to each class and then concatenating the dictionary into a huge list but that does not seem to work. I believe I was thinking in the right direction but I am quite inexperienced in this regard.

Here's a basic outline of how you can accomplish this:
Integer Labeling
class_to_index = {class_label: i for i, class_label in enumerate(preprocessed_data.keys())}

Concatenation
data = []
labels = []
for class_label, sequences in preprocessed_data.items():
    label = class_to_index[class_label]
    for sequence in sequences:
        data.append(sequence)
        labels.append(label)

TensorFlow Dataset Creation
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((data, labels))

Shuffle and batch the dataset as needed
batch_size = 32
dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=len(data)).batch(batch_size)

Optionally, you can also apply other transformations like normalization or augmentation etc.
Now, the 'dataset' can be fed into a 1D CNN model
